# Update specific fields only using save method in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am developing an app in express that uses mongodb. I wrote the code to insert and update the data using save method that works fine.

**Working code**

```
dbconnect.collection('profiles').save(data, function (err, result) {
            if (err)
                return res.send({ success: false, message: "Error saving into database" });
            result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
            if (_.isEmpty(result) || !result.ok)
                return res.send({ success: false, message: "Unidentified error." })
            return res.send({ success: true });
        });
```

If i update the data, the whole document is getting updated. Yes as its said. But i want to omit one field out of it.

let say my fields are

```
username, password, email, postal_address
```

if i pass without _id, it creates a new _id and the document is inserted.

if the user is trying to update the postal_address, it deletes the password as the data doesn't contain password field. Its like rewriting the whole document.

As the code has been written and i dont want to break the code into two parts as insert and update, i am looking for a way i could update part of the document using save itself.

Hope i made my question clear.

Comment: You could also use `update` with the `upsert` option, so it would still be just one step.

Comment: It's explained [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-option)

Comment: I finally splitted my code. Thanks for your time and update

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, You don't want to use multiple commands for inserts and updates.

You can make use of update command with `upsert` option set to true.
You can find the documents using some query selector and use `"$set"` and `"$setOnInsert"` operators in the update object.

`"$setOnInsert"` can be used to add fields on some custom logic, which will only be applied if the document is upserted and not updated.

`db.collection.update(query, update, {upsert: true})`

```
`db.products.update(
 { name: 'Apple' },
  {
     $set: { item: "apple" },
     $setOnInsert: { defaultQty: 100 }
  },
  { upsert: true }
)`
```

Refer here for more : [MongoDB $setOnInsert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/)

You have to choose your query selector carefully because when you will not provide any field in query selector, it will match any of the document and will update that particular document. So, better use some solid query selector and not use `_id` in your query selector as per your requirement and let the upsert automatically create `_id` (OR set `_id` using "$setOnInsert")

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately i had _id as reference. I dont want to change it. So I couldnt make your reference to workout. Thanks for your time and update.